# The verbs for book pages?

Tags: verbs

What is the verbs for book pages? For example, can we say that someone turns a book from page 3 to page 4? Or turn the pages? Thank you very much!

Comment: You are right. You turn pages, you turn to page 4.

Comment: Thank you ! What I try to express is that some book pages are stiff and difficult to be turned.

Comment: Apart from that, you can try; *Flip through the pages* and *go through the leaves of the book*

Comment: Yes, use *turn*. But we turn "[from page X] to page Y" or we can "turn the page". We don't *"turn the book" :)

Comment: @Araucaria - ""turns a book ..."seems fine to me. The reader could be turning magazine pages. So "Ralph turned the book from page to page." We don't know if Ralph is reading or just looking at the pictures though.

Comment: @MaxW Yes, I think you're right. I more meant we don't normally say "he turned the book from page one to page two". You're right :)

Comment: I also say 'Go to page x from y'

Comment: All of these suggestions seem fine. An additional one, if you are going to start at a specific page (maybe a textbook in class) you could say "open the book to page 34"

Comment: Thank hou very much! It is  very helpful. Now I know the verbs for pages could be flip, turn, and go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solutions for your question:

> "Turn the page", "Turn to page 4" or "Turn one page"